# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Address not available)

Tags: docker-compose, mariadb, fastapi

I got the above error when trying to connect to MariaDB from outside docker container. Below is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        ports:
            - "127.0.0.1:3309:3306"
        volumes: 
            - mariadb_volume:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
            MYSQL_DATABASE: mydatabase
            MYSQL_USER: myuser
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
        networks:
            - fastapi_network
            
    fastapi-dev:
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: fastapi-dev:latest
        container_name: fastapi-dev
        command: /start-reload.sh
        volumes: 
            - ./src:/app/src
        ports:
            - 5000:80
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
        networks:
            - fastapi_network
     
volumes:
    mariadb_volume:
        driver: local
                      
networks:
  fastapi_network:
    external: true
```

My DB config for DB connection is here:

```
class DbSettings(BaseSettings):
    db_username:str = 'myuser'
    db_password: str = 'mypassword'
    db_host: str = 'localhost'
    db_port: int = '3306'
    db_name: str = 'mydatabase'

    engine_echo = True
    session_autocommit = False
    session_autoflush = False

    @property
    def db_conn_str(self) -> AnyUrl:
        return AnyUrl.build(
            scheme="mysql+pymysql",
            user=self.db_username,
            password=self.db_password,
            host=self.db_host,
            port=str(self.db_port),
            path=f"/{self.db_name}"
        )
```

After deploying the container with 'docker-compose up', I can see the server is completely up and run as below:

```
mariadb_1              | 2021-09-06  8:24:10 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mariadb_1              | Version: '10.6.4-MariaDB-1:10.6.4+maria~focal'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Given that the server is running and accepting connections, I can't quite understand what went wrong with the code. Can someone advise me on this please?

Comment: You host is named like a service in docker-compose, in this case `mariadb`

Comment: @BartoszKarwacki: I don't think the name matters here, it's just a service name

Answer (score 1):

I just found a mistake where db_host should be 'mariadb' instead of 'localhost'. After this change, it works now.